# Can i create my own gym when i reach certain gym level or user level?

Tags: pokemon-go

There's just one gym in my city and way to many players, so it's very competitive around here....i think i've read somewhere that this was suppoused to be a big feature for this game so i was wondering if it's possible to do so like right now or do we have to wait until an update that make that option avalaible?

Answer (score 1):

As the user Kiwi stated you would have them be added through Ingress, the other Niantic Labs game; however, at the time of posting I believe they have stopped portal submissions. You can not submit portals in ingress since September of 2015.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible and I don't think it will be possible.

The main reason : If you can create gym or pokéstop, everybody gonna create a gym and a pokéstop at their house. 100% garanted. But Pokémon Go main goal is clearly to make us move and explore. So, no point to let players adding them.

And I think the idea of the gym is to be competitive. Too much gym isn't gonna help. Maybe they will add some in specific area, but a few and not by the players.

Comment: In my small town we have 10 gyms, but that's because Ingress was pretty big here (Netherlands), therefore all monuments have been marked and added as gyms or pokestops. Not sure if it is still possible to get locations added through Ingress?